# Should I avoid the error "Variable 'foo' is used before it has been assigned a value.'?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm working in VB.NET Framework 4.8 in Visual Studio 2019.

I have a module that goes like this:

```
Dim foo As JObject

If a OrElse b Then
    foo = GetSomeValue()
    '...
End If

If a Then
    Bar(foo)
    '...
End If
```

I'm getting a warning on bar(foo) saying "Variable 'foo' is used before it has been assigned a value."  Logically it's impossible for that to be the case. If a is true, foo is assigned a value. If a is false, foo is not used.  I structured the if statements this way because it seemed best - less repetition and chance of error. (In my real code, the inside of the IF statements is considerably larger)

However I wonder if I'm doing something improper - if best practice would be to avoid the error and write it in a different way. Or am I right and just confusing an overly simplistic error check?

Comment: This warning is generated by VS. For intellicode “if a OrElse b then” may be False then “foo” have not an assignment. TO avoid this as warning just assign a initial value as Nothing (if you are sure foo value will be assigned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to ensure that the compiler can see that that variable will always be assigned to. Your logic won't be examined closely enough to see that that is already the case so you have to make it more obvious. The solution is simple. This line:

```vb
dim foo as JObject
```

implicitly sets `foo` to `Nothing`, because that is the default value for all variables. You can simply make that explicit:

```vb
dim foo as JObject = Nothing
```

That will suppress the warning because the compiler will assume that you specifically want that variable to be `Nothing` so you will take responsibility for making sure that it doesn't generate a `NullReferenceException`.